# How use Safari with Selenium 2.0?

Tags: c#, testing, selenium, safari

I want to know how to use Safari with Selenium 2.0 [Selenium IDE 1.7.2] using C#...Any suggestion?

Comment: Is there something special about Safari that prevents you from using Selenium in the usual way, using the instructions that come with Selenium?

Comment: The thing is that I can't find the instructions for using Safari

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately **Selenium IDE** is for **Firefox only**. To use Selenium with Safari you will have to use one of the Selenium programming libraries (Java, C#, etc.)

Comment: Yes I'm using C# but I can't find any library...I found one but for Java

Comment: That library doesn't have a support for Safari.

Comment: Looks like version 2.21 will have a SafariDriver: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=16549

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at the [Telerik Testing Framework](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/free-testing-framework.aspx), a free web test framework which underpins [our commercial Test Studio product](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools).

With the testing framework you can write one test and run it against IE, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. You can author tests in C# or VB.NET.

The framework is free; however, you can also purchase paid support packages if you so desire.

(Disclosure: I'm the Test Studio evangelist for Telerik)